# Swift 2.0 Force Protocol

Tags: swift2

I was wondering if there's a way to enforce protocol's on subclassing particular classes?

an example is:

```
protocol MYWindowControllerProtocol {
    var identifier: String { get }
}
```

then later in I create a subclass of NSWindowController in order to inherit the needs I've laid out above:

```
class MYWindowController: NSWindowController, MYWindowControllerProtocol{
}
```

The problem I have is that it requires the subclass to inherit the protocol needs (which makes sense)... Is there a way about this so that only subclasses of "MYWindowController" actually have to inherit the needs? Without my base `MYWIndowController` class being forced to?

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1) Ensuring that anything subclassed from `MYWindowController` is required to implement various functions or vars per the protocol
2) Tha the actual class MYWindowController (the parent `MYWindowCOntroller`) isn't forced to, as it's merely an abstract class

Cheers,

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this at compile time in Swift (there are languages that have the concept of an `abstract` class, like Java, which you can do this with at compile time).  Your only option is a run-time solution.  In your base class, you can provide implementations that call fatalError(String) and pass a message like "Subclass must provide implementation of method/variable <#signature#>".  This will cause the app to fail at runtime if no implementation is provided, so it is a little risky if it isn't absolutely going to happen (i.e., could be overlooked in testing).

```
var identifier: String {
    get {
        fatalError("Subclass must provide implementation for var identifier")
    }
}
```

**Note**: I would suggest that you could use Swift 2's protocol extensions to accomplish the same thing, but there appears to be a bug with method dispatch when you have a class that conforms to a protocol and provides no implementation, the subclass implementation is not dispatched correctly.

Comment: Thanks..  was hoping this wasn't the case, but it seems as flexible swift is, it isn't extendible to this extent... Thanks though..

Comment: Swift is a Protocol Oriented Language, so forcing something to default from it's protocol would be totally breaking the point of swift. Thats akin to hiring a pole-dancer to fix a car (rather than a mechanic)...